# Laravel HasManyThrough returns empty collection

Tags: laravel

I am attempting to use HasManyThrough (which I think might be incorrect) to return the value of a column from a table via an intermediate table. From the File model I am attempting to access the Game table. The relations are:

- A game can have many mods.
- Many mods can have many files.

---

My table schema:

### File Table

`id` - primary key
`mod_id` - foreign key

### Mod Table

`id` - primary key
`game_id` - foreign key

### Game Table

`id` - primary key

---

And this is how I am attempting to link them, I think the issue is there is only one Game for all the files I am attempting to find however I am not sure what the singular equivalent of HasManyThrough is?

In files.php the method I am attempting to use to map the relation is the following:

```
public function game()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Game', 
        'App\Mod', 
        'id',
        'id', 
        'mod_id', 
        'game_id'
    );
}
```

And I am attempting to get it via the following call:

```
$data = App\Files::with('game')->get();
```

Funny enough if I dump & die right after calling the above method it returns the game objects, but as soon as I attempt to eager load the relation, it returns an empty collection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try App\Files::with('game')->get();

Comment: Sorry that's what I was doing, still the same result - editing my post to fix the typo.

Comment: Could you please show us how you are having game object when dd??

Comment: Could a *file* have many games through a mod? I think your relationship is wrong. If your `Files` model has a `mod` function **(for relationship with mod)**. Try `App\Files::with('mod.game')`, where `game` is a relation of *mod* to *game*.

Comment: @Wreigh I have since discovered that however, the issue is that loads the game object into the mod object's getRelations() array. Is there any way to have it so I can access the game via the File objects getRelation() method call.

Comment: why do you need it from the `File` object?

Comment: The File object uses a [transformer](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/) that other transformers can load and use, if I hardcode it as getting the game via the mod object, chances are it would break because other transformers wouldn't have eager loaded the respective relationship.